# KeyError when trying to get to a value in 2d array (imported from csv file)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I need a code in which I load data from several csv files (containing distance, altitude, angle, wavelength etc.)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

date = 20180710
# import csv files
geometry = pd.read_csv('20180710_geo.csv', sep=';')
TWOb = pd.read_csv('l2b.csv', sep=';')
calib = pd.read_csv('calibration.csv', sep=';')
obs = pd.read_csv('observation.csv', sep=';')

###### extract position of date in obs #########
idxtupple = np.where(obs == date)
listidx = list(zip(idxtupple[0], idxtupple[1]))
for idx in listidx:
    print(idx)

D = obs[idx[0],7]
print(D)
```

Everything seems fine, I have the correct number of lines and columns, and correct float numbers at each positions. But when I try to get an element in the 2d array (for instance obs[18,7] or geometry[2,5]), I get "`KeyError: (18, 7)`" (or `KeyError: (2, 5)` etc.) and I don't get why...

Here's what I get as csv file (from row 15 to 19 of my obs file):

```
Date of acq. [yyyymmdd]  Operation      ... Altitude min [km]        Comments
15                 20180630  Check out  ...            19,51              NaN
16                 20180703  Check out  ...               NaN             NaN
17                 20180705       Dark  ...               NaN             NaN
19                 20180711      Box-A  ...            19,52   Global mapping
```

Comment: It would be better if you can post a minimal reproducible example including data, e.g. remove the csv reads in favour of defining some static data that represents the problem.

Comment: obs is **not** a 2D array but a pandas `DataFrame`. If you want the value of the `Operation` column and index 17 you should use `obs.loc[17, 'Operation']. Alternatively, if you want value of the first column and 17th row, you could use `obs.iloc[17, 0]`. But IMHO you should read the pandas tutorial if you want to use (even minimaly) dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, Serge Ballesta!

I managed to get the wanted value in the table with `str = obs.loc[idx[0], 'Solar distance [au]']` and then just converted it with `D = float(str.replace(',', '.'))` and it works.